# Python: How to strip string in pandas.Series?

Tags: python, string, pandas, strip

I have `list_of_items` list with string objects. And I want to make a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) out of it. I am using the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_items = [
    'osobní automobil',
    'osobní automobil',
    'osobní automobil',
    'přípojné vozidlo - přívěs',
    'osobní automobil',
    'osobní automobil',
    'osobní automobil',
    'přípojné vozidlo - přívěs',
    'osobní automobil',
    'osobní automobil'
]
my_series = pd.Series(list_of_items)
```

And I am getting the following result.

```
>>> print(my_series)
0                  osobní automobil
1                  osobní automobil
2                  osobní automobil
3    přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
4                  osobní automobil
5                  osobní automobil
6                  osobní automobil
7    přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
8                  osobní automobil
9                  osobní automobil
```

However, I expect this:

```
0             osobní automobil
1             osobní automobil
2             osobní automobil
3    přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
4             osobní automobil
5             osobní automobil
6             osobní automobil
7    přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
8             osobní automobil
9             osobní automobil
```

The wierd is, that when I try to strip the items in `my_series`, the result is still the same:

```
>>> print(my_series.str.strip())
0                  osobní automobil
1                  osobní automobil
2                  osobní automobil
3    přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
4                  osobní automobil
5                  osobní automobil
6                  osobní automobil
7    přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
8                  osobní automobil
9                  osobní automobil
```

Please, can you help me, what am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

If there is a rendering alignment issue, could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not aligned, but the result is ok: `'přípojné vozidlo - přívěs'` from `my_series[3]`

Comment: it seems that any letter with an accent add a white space in the print alignment, try with one item being `osobni automobil` (with a i without accent). also with `my_series.str.encode('utf-8')` you don't have misalignment anymore, but it is not nice to see this way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ben T. mentioned in comments - if I deaccent the items, then there is no longer the problem with bad alignment. For this purpose, [`gensim.utils.deaccent`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.deaccent) can be used.

```
>>> import gensim
>>> my_series = my_series.apply(gensim.utils.deaccent)
>>> print(my_series)
0             osobni automobil
1             osobni automobil
2             osobni automobil
3    pripojne vozidlo - prives
4             osobni automobil
5             osobni automobil
6             osobni automobil
7    pripojne vozidlo - prives
8             osobni automobil
9             osobni automobil
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is fine, it just seems to be a rendering alignment issue

This can be validated by printing out the individual items

```
>>> for item in my_series: print('"'+item+'"')
... 
"osobní automobil"
"osobní automobil"
"osobní automobil"
"přípojné vozidlo - přívěs"
"osobní automobil"
"osobní automobil"
"osobní automobil"
"přípojné vozidlo - přívěs"
"osobní automobil"
"osobní automobil"
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Do you know, how to solve this rendering alignment issue, please?

Comment: Datarames have a style object, for when you are editing in a juypter notebook. But series has no `.style` attribute. Sorry, cant help you further.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. This is a hard fixed solution but it worked.

```
_ = [print("{:>26}".format(item)) for item in my_series]
```

**Output**

```
         osobní automobil
         osobní automobil
         osobní automobil
přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
         osobní automobil
         osobní automobil
         osobní automobil
přípojné vozidlo - přívěs
         osobní automobil
         osobní automobil
```